# Widening Conversion between Reference types

Tags: c#, type-conversion, reference-type

I know that in a widening conversion, the destination data type can hold any value provided by the source data type. I can understand this when convert value type,
but can't between reference types. My question arises from follows scenario:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string SurName { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee { Name = "Elvin", SurName = "Mammadov" };
    Person prs = emp;
}
```

As shown, the *Person* class is ancestor class of *Empoyee*. In previouse code, I create reference of *Emplyee* class, and then convert *Employee* object into a Person. At this point, I lose *SurName* data field and value.

I want to know:

1. Is it countary to ***can hold any value*** expression?
2. Why conversion a reference type to a direct or indirect ancestor class or interface is a widening conversion?

thanks for reply

Comment: SurName is still there, as you can see if you cast prs back into an Employee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be called a 'widening conversion' because you're becoming less specific with regard to the references type, you're widening the set of potential types. When you have an `Employee` reference you know that you can use any functionality specific to that class, when you have a `Person` reference to the same object you only know that you can use functionality contained in the `Person` class. If you want to use `Employee` specific functionality with your `prs` reference you'll first have to cast your reference back to an `Employee` reference and if `prs` isn't actually of type `Employee` (perhaps it's of type `Customer` which also inherits from `Person`) then you will get an `InvalidCastException`.

The `SurName` property does not go away when you're dealing with a `Person` reference. You just cannot access it because it is not contained within the `Person` class. Basically, if you have a reference of the base classes type, you will only be able to access properties/methods contained within the base class. It doesn't matter that it is actually an `Employee`, you have a `Person` reference, so the object is treated accordingly.

The conversion is not useful in your example. The conversion is useful when you're attempting to work with many child classes in a generic manner. As an example, I may have a `Person` class. In addition to that I have `Employee`, `Customer`, and `Consultant` classes which inherit from it. Now lets suppose I have a `Store` object and I want to do something like get the names of every `Person` who is currently in the store. The simplest way to solve this problem would be to have a `List<Person>` with all the people in the store. Because `Employee`, `Customer`, and `Consultant` all inherit from `Person` I could do

```
peopleInMyStore.Add(MyEmployee);
peopleInMyStore.Add(MyCustomer);
peopleInMyStore.Add(MyConsultant);
```

Then later on I can do something like;

```
foreach (Person p in peopleInMyStore)
{
     Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

This concept is referred to as 'polymorphism' and can be read about here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

My example is contrived, but this is one of the main reasons you use inheritance. To give you a real example I have some test code where I have a class called `ApiTestSuite` then I have about a dozen classes that all inherit from it of the form `SpecificApiTestSuite`. The project builds into a command line executable, you invoke it with an api parameter (api=specificApiName) then I can do something like;

```
 ApiTestSuite tests;
 if (args[0] == "api1")
     tests = new Api1TestSuite();
 else
     tests = new Api2TestSuite();
 tests.RunTests();
```

Comment: But I can't access to it. How it would be useful after conversion? please, explain to me.