# c# - Narrowing and widening on class inheritance

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm studying for the 70-483 exam and  I have doubts about converting types.
I follow a book, at the end of each chapter there are some questions/answer, and with one i'm completly confuse.

> If the Manager class inherits from the Employee class, and the Employee and Customer classes both inherit from the Person class, then which of the following are narrowing conversions?
>
> > a.    Converting a Person to a Manager
> >
> > b.    Converting an Employee to a Manager
> >
> > c.    Converting an Employee to a Person
> >
> > d.    Converting a Manager to a Person
> >
> > e.    Converting a Manager to an Employee
> >
> > f.    Converting a Person to an Employee
> >
> > g.    Converting a Customer to an Employee
> >
> > h.    Converting an Employee to a Customer

the answers are :

> > "A, B, F . (In a sense you could technically consider g and h to be considered narrowing conversions, but actually they are just invalid conversions.)"

From what i understand, i thought a,b,f to be widening conversions

- A widening conversion is a conversion where every value of the
  original type can be represented in the result type.
- A narrowing conversion is a conversion where some values of the
  original type cannot be represented in the result type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I do

```
Person originalType = new Customer();
Employee resultType = (Employee)originalType; //this line is Example f in the book.
```

The 2nd line would fail with a invalid cast exception. That means there is a value that `Person` can be that will fail when you convert to `Employee`.

If you look at your two rules again (emphasis mine)

> - A widening conversion is a conversion where **every value of the original type** can be represented in the result type.
> - A narrowing conversion is a conversion where some values of the original type cannot be represented in the result type.

You will see this will fall under the 2nd rule because we did find a value of the original type that could not be represented as the result type.

Comment: So we can say that converting a reference type to a direct or indirect ancestor  is a widening conversion. (And in fact it dont need explicit cast).

Comment: Correct, most things with a implicit cast are widening conversions. That is why they allow them to be implicit. Most things that are narrowing conversions require a explicit cast to do (in the base .NET framework, in custom classes you can do all sorts of weird stuff with implicit and explicit casts).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412712/widening-conversion-between-reference-types for details

Answer (score 3):

Converting a `Person` to a `Manager` is not widening, since not all `Person` objects (the original type) can be represented in the result type. Why? Because `Customer` is also a `Person` and `Customer` can not be `Manager`.

But if we were to convert from `Manager` to `Person`, that we can do for every `Manager` object. There is no `Manager` we can not convert to a `Person`. Hence this is widening.

Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Narrowing is when you create a class for a subset of a bigger group, to store additional data mostly.

So when you convert a person to an employee, you are looking at it from the perspective of a smaller/narrower group/type (an employee is a person but a person is not necessarly an employee).

The same apply for converting an Employee to a Manager and converting a Person to an Employee